# laravel load function with DB::table

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

How can I use Laravel `load` function with `DB::table` as following

```
DB::table('table_name)->where('field', 'value')->load('relation_1')->get();
```

or an alternative to this statement

Comment: Please review the help center and learn how to ask question on stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: The `DB` query builder doesn't handle relationships. These are done with `Eloquent` models.

Answer (score 0):

You can write directly like

```
DB::table('users')->get();
```

or

```
DB::table('users')
    ->select(DB::raw('count(*) as user_count, status'))
    ->where('status', '<>', 1)
    ->groupBy('status')
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Post::all()->where('field_name', 'value')->load('relation_1','relation_2');
```

I could not use load function with DB::table
I created a Model named Post and I used the where function and load